# View / Edit Contact on Android

Tags: android, edit, contacts, overriding

I am trying to add these functionality in my Android app:

1) Get A list of suggested contacts from a Web Service and Display them in a list view
- This I have implemented and working fine

2) When User selects any of these contacts I want to present them in Native Contact View. My fried who is iPhone developer was able to do this with help of ABPerson class which provides feature to display the contact in native contact view page without adding the contact to contact list. I am not able to find any such API in Andoid. Please suggest.

3) When User want to edit any contact in the above list, I am able to present Edit Contact activity from native Phone Book app. This is working fine, but I am not able to remove the Done and Revert button. Unfortunately due to this, if user click on Done that contact is added to phone, however, what I want to do here is that, user can modify the data and I will keep it in the memory till the export process starts. During the export process I will insert these records in the Phone Book.

Please suggest me how can I do this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Hi, I am facing exactly the same problem here..were you able to solve this? if so could you tell me how because i've been looking for a solution but couldn't find one..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you look over the [BusinessCard sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BusinessCard/index.html) and [ContactManager sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html) posted on the Android developer site.

Reading carefully through both of these is what helped me understand exactly what's going on in the contacts API.

Comment: hi phoenix i have gone through those tutorials but still i haven't got any solution ,what exactly i want to do is just open the native Edit Contact Activity (which is working fine) and then (the part which I am not able to implement) override the DONE and REVERT button functionality with my logic.  so can u suggest me how to do that.

Comment: Muni,

You won't be able to override anything built-in without download the Android source and writing a custom class.  I suggest you work with what is given to you and use startActivityForResult() and the callbacks provided by that method.